# Call ViewController when applicationDidEnterBackground in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, bluetooth, background, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I am working on an app that scans for a specific UUID Bluetooth device in the background (App in background) and connects with it (ViewController is called "BluetoothScanVC".

If I display the "BluetoohScanVC" and press the home button everything works as planned and the device connects as soon as the UUID is in reach. But when I display another ViewController (i.e. "FirstVC") i can not get it run.

I tried to call the BluetoothScanVC().viewdidload() in AppDelegate -  applicationDidEnterBackground but without success.

I can not figure out how to call/run this function in BluetoothScanVC:

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)...

when closing the app and displayed another VC before.

Answer (score -1):

The functionality you are using to detect these bluetooth devices should not live in a single ViewController, as it is going to be deallocated. If you want something to happen from anywhere in your application or in the background, you should checkout possibly creating a singleton that is called in the AppDelegate, or simply placing the code for scanning for bluetooth devices in the AppDelegate itself.

Your AppDelegate might look something like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  beginScanningForDevices()
  return true
}

func beginScanningForDevices() {
  // Code to scan for bluetooth devices
}
```